# Angular 2 Import Service into Component

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am trying to import a service into a component that is in a different directory, but I keep getting a `cannot find module error` on the service import.

directory structure:

[image]

//Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AtmService } from '../services/atm.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-atm-list',
  templateUrl: './atm-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./atm-list.component.css']
})
export class AtmListComponent implements OnInit {

  atms: Array<any>;

  constructor(private atmService: AtmService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.atmService.getAtms().subscribe{
      data => {
        this.atms = data;
      },
      error => console.error(error)
    };
  }

}
```

Comment: Maybe try to you use IDE that searches for imports automatically :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `import { AtmService } from '../../services/atm.service';`

You need to go two folders back to get access to `services` folder.

Comment: This was helpful in my case also.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

your are trying to access service from component folder

you can go two level back or you can drill down from app folder like this `app/services/atm.service`

```
import { AtmService } from 'app/services/atm.service';
```

Comment: This is the most maintainable solution but you need to set a `baseUrl` for it to work. Both your tsconfig.json and your loader or bundler configuration will need to be updated